# generator: pre-processing events at fixed offset

Tags: python, generator

I have a generator yielding events and I would like to enrich it with additional metadata I can fetch from an API.

Some events have an object id linked to them and other events have the object's hash, but not both. I cannot fetch the object id based on the hash, I can only do id->hash.

I would like to have both the id and hash fields in all events, by "looking ahead" of the generator only a fixed number of events, and  build a two-way mapping between ids and hashes. I don't wanna go over the entire iterable twice (first to build the mapping and then to print it).

Assuming I have a `populate_mapping` method and a `encrich_event` method (both receive one event at a time), where `populate_mapping` updates a global dictionary  and `encrich_event` uses that dictionary, I would like them to be called in such a way that `populate_mapping` has processed exactly `N` events more than `encrich_event`, and that the results of `enrich_event` are still lazy-evaluated and available through a generator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you put the question is very abstract, but it seems you're trying to use the `itertools.tee` function that can split an iterator in two

```
x1, x2 = itertools.tee(your_generator, 2)
```

then skip the first 4 elements from the first iterator:

```
x1 = itertools.islice(x1, 4, None)
```

pass the x1 to one function and x2 to the other, and x1 will be 4 elements ahead, no extra elements will be consumed unless needed (the tee function context will store the 4 elements internally in its scope)

Comment: Guess you're referring to `itertools.islice`?

Comment: Thanks and sorry for the poor question description!
Two corrections though: I wanna consume those skipped elements, so I'll iterate over `x1` `N` times instead of using `islice`, and I wanna advance once in `x1` every time `x2` advances once, so i'll wrap it in another generator that calls both.